# What is the Extinction of the Shape-shifters (like Beorn) in Middle-Earth Lore?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, shape-shifter

In the movie [The Hobbit, The Desolation of Smaug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit%3a_The_Desolation_of_Smaug) - the party wind up at [Beorn's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beorn) [Hall](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Beorn%27s_Hall). When Beorn is asked about other Shape-Shifters he makes reference to a past event where [Azog](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Azog) captured the shape-shifters and tortured them for his own entertainment.

My question is - **is there any mention in the Hobbit, LoTR, Silmarillion or other letters for the extinction of the Shapeshifters?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, because Beorn wasn't the last of the skin-changers.

The eradication of the skin-changers was made up for the film. The "Beornings" were led by a son of Beorn during the War of the Ring, when they helped Aragorn cross the Anduin while tracking Gollum. After the war, the elves gave them part of Mirkwood to live in.

Comment: Peter Jackson should write a book so some creative genius can make it into a movie.

Comment: My stomach turns when I think that Peter Jackson may even now, as we speak, be working on The Silmarillion.

Comment: The studios don't have the rights to The Silmarillion, and will probably never get them. Christopher Tolkien: "They gutted the book, making an action movie for 15-25 year olds. And it seems that The Hobbit will be of the same ilk. Tolkien became...devoured by his popularity and absorbed by the absurdity of the time. The gap widened between the beauty, the seriousness of the work, and what it has become is beyond me. This level of marketing reduces to nothing the aesthetic and philosophical significance of this work." The estate also had to sue to get any money from the LotR movies.

Comment: I'll agree that Jackson is going a bit far on the Hobbit trilogy, but I have to disagree with CT on the LotR trilogy. That one - especially the Extended Editions - is simply one of the most magnificent epics ever put to film.